# Question about Lie bracket and right invariant vector fields

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-fields

So I was thinking about the Lie bracket of right-invariant vector fields. For starters,

> Let $X, Y \in \mathcal{X}(M)$ be smooth vector fields. The Lie bracket of $X$ and $Y$ is the vector field $[X,Y] \in \mathcal{X}(M)$ given by
> $$ [X, Y] (f)= X(Y(f))-Y(X(f)), \forall f \in C^{\infty}(M).$$

It is also known that (*Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* by John M. Lee, Propositions 8.30 and 8.31) we have $F_{\ast} [X,Y] = [F_{\ast} X, F_{\ast} Y]$ whenever $F$ is a diffeomorphism by the naturality of the Lie bracket. Now, a right-invariant vector field is a vector field $X$ such that $(R_g)_{\ast} X = X $. The proof that the Lie bracket of two left-invariant vector fields is a left-invariant vector field goes by using that
$$(L_g)_{\ast} [X,Y] = [(L_g)_{\ast} X, (L_g)_{\ast} Y].$$
By the same logic, couldn't I show that the Lie bracket of two right-invariant vector fields is a right-invariant vector field? That is,
$$(R_g)_{\ast} [X,Y] = [(R_g)_{\ast} X, (R_g)_{\ast} Y].$$

The reasoning why I'm asking this is because it seems that the Lie bracket of right invariant vector fields will come with a minus sign, as shown [in this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55679/lie-bracket-of-invariant-vector-fields), that doesn't appear in my derivation of the formula.